# How can i count the number of columns that have non zero entries across rows? pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below and would like to create a new column which counts the number of non-zero entries.

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 
0    |  0   |  2   |  3   | 0 
0    |  0   |  0   |  3   | 0 
0    |  0   |  8   |  3   | 0 
0    |  2   |  2   |  3   | 0
```

e..g like below:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | nonzero 
0    |  0   |  2   |  3   | 0    | 2
0    |  0   |  0   |  3   | 0    | 1
0    |  0   |  8   |  3   | 0    | 2
0    |  2   |  2   |  3   | 0    | 3
```

how can i do this?

Comment: `df['nonzero'] = df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: ```df['nonzero'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(bool).sum(), axis=1)```